# Contravariance in Expressions

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, covariance, contravariance

I'm trying to create a Generic Action Delegate

```
  delegate void ActionPredicate<in T1, in T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2);
```

and

```
public static ActionPredicate<T,string> GetSetterAction<T>(string fieldName) 
    {

        ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Target");
        MemberExpression fieldExpr = Expression.Property(targetExpr, fieldName);
        ParameterExpression valueExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");

        MethodCallExpression convertExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), "ChangeType", null, valueExpr, Expression.Constant(fieldExpr.Type));

        UnaryExpression valueCast = Expression.Convert(convertExpr, fieldExpr.Type);
        BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(fieldExpr, valueCast);
        var result = Expression.Lambda<ActionPredicate<T, string>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr);
        return result.Compile();
    }
```

and here is my caller

```
 ActionPredicate<busBase, string> act = DelegateGenerator.GetSetterAction<busPerson>("FirstName");
```

and here is the business object

```
 public abstract class busBase 
{

}
public class busPerson : busBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

and here is the error what i get during compilation

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'BusinessObjects.ActionPredicate<BusinessObjects.busPerson,string>' to 'BusinessObjects.ActionPredicate<BusinessObjects.busBase,string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

My GetSetterAction is returning ActionPerdicate where as here T is busPerson and i am trying to store it in ActionPredicate keeping in mind about Contravariance. But it fails. i dont know how to proceed further. Please Help..!

Comment: Did you try the explicit conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generic contravariance does *not* allow you to assign a delegate `D<TDerived>` to a delegate `D<TBase>` because of the reason demonstrated below (using `Action<T1>` here):

```
Action<string> m1 = MyMethod; //some method to call
Action<object> m2 = m1; //compiler error - but pretend it's not.
object obj = new object();

m2(obj);  //runtime error - not type safe
```

As you can see, if we were allowed to do this assignment, we would then be breaking type-safety because we'd be able to try and invoke the delegate `m1` by passing and instance of `object` and not `string`.  Going the other way, however, i.e. copying a delegate reference to a type whose parameter type is more derived than the source is fine.  [MSDN has a more complete example of generic co/contra variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#DelegateVariantTypeParameters.).

Therefore you will either need to change the declaration of `act` to `ActionPredicate<busPerson, string> act` or, more likely, consider writing the `GetSetterAction` method to always return `ActionPredicate<busBase, string>`.  If you do that, you should also add the type constraint

```
where T1 : busBase
```

To the method, and you'll also need to change how your expression is built, replace the first two lines as follows:

```
ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(busBase), "Target");
//generate a strongly-typed downcast to the derived type from busBase and
//use that as the type on which the property is to be written
MemberExpression fieldExpr = Expression.Property(
  Expression.Convert(targetExpr, typeof(T1)), fieldName);
```

Adding the generic constraint is a nice touch to ensure that this downcast will always be valid for any `T1`.

On a slightly different note - what was wrong with the `Action<T1, T2>` delegate?  It seems to do exactly the same thing as yours? :)

Comment: As you suggested, i tried to change GeetSetterAction to return Action<busBase,string> but i ended up with this error       "ParameterExpression of type 'BusinessObjects.busPerson' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'BusinessObjects.busBase'". I am getting this error at this line.  "var result = Expression.Lambda<Action<busBase, I>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr);"

Comment: @kans - ah yes - you'll have to build the expression tree slightly differently: downcast from `busBase` to `T1` when generating `fieldExpr`.  Have updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. it works great. I am creating a Rules Engine based on Expressions. Can you throw some of your thoughts on this..

Comment: Expressions are immensely powerful and incredibly useful; and the easiest way by far to do dynamic code.  Not least because you can *understand* them in code, by walking the tree with a visitor. One word of advice, though, don't expect your colleagues to understand them.  The subject is one if those that you have to *want* to learn, and in my experience most people don't!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you throw some piece of code if u have any about the rules xml/c# code etc if somethings comes to your maid or somethings which will help me to have a jumpstart and also about Visitor.

Comment: Hi @kans, this is such a massive topic its difficult to just fire some code at you.  I strongly suggest just 'following your nose', start out with an idea of the simplest functionality you can think of, and how the xml will look, and develop it test-first with unit tests.  I have an IOC I've written for use in-house that builds code via expressions, and I did that all test-first.  It made adding new features a lot easier.