# A generic type <TGen> where TGen : SomeType cannot be matched by SomeType using Expression trees

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, expression-trees

I have an `Encounter` type and a `Response` that inherits it:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Request), typeof(Response))]
public abstract class Encounter {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
// .. some more Encounter subtypes ...
public class Response : Encounter {
    public bool IsResponded;
}
```

I want to be able to pass an `Encounter` or a subtype of it to the `Db.UpdateEncounterAsync()` method:

```
class Db {
    private IMongoCollection<Encounter> EncounersCollection;
    // ... stuff ...
    public Db() {
        EncounersCollection = InitCollection();
    }
    // ... stuff ...
    public async Task UpdateEncounterAsync<TEncounter, TField>(
        TEncounter encounter, Expression<Func<TEncounter, TField>> fieldFuncExpr)
        where TEncounter : Encounter
    {
        var value = fieldFuncExpr.Compile()(encounter);
        var updateDefinition = Builders<Encounter>.Update
            .Set(fieldFuncExpr, value); // Error CS1503

        var updateResult = await EncounersCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
            e => e.Id == encounter.Id, updateDefinition);
    }
}
```

In the following way:

```
Response response = GetResponse();
response.IsResponded = true;
// update just the IsResponded field of the response object:
UpdateEncounterAsync(response, r => r.IsResponded);
```

But my `UpdateEncounterAsync` doesn't compile:

`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEncounter, TField>>' to 'MongoDB.Driver.FieldDefinition<DataModel.Encounter, TField>'`

That's because `fieldFuncExpr` is of type `Expression<Func<TEncounter, TField>>`, `where TEncounter : Encounter`, but `Builders<Encounter>.Update.Set(expr, value)` expects `expr` of type `Expression<Func<Encounter, TField>>` and not the generic `TEncounter`.

Is there an elegant way around it?

Comment: that's likely the delegate `Contravariance` at work - did you try specifying the generic parameter in `Set` like `Set<TEncounter>` as that seems to be generic as well (and your field is TEcounter etc.). It may also be due to you using the `Builders<Encounter>` so that's where you should start I think. It's hard to tell for sure, w/o `a small working example`, it's much easier to reason with a code in front. And I have no clue about MongoDb. In short you can't cast Func<TEncounter...> to Func<Encounter>, e.g. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10102063/417747)

Comment: @NSGaga, I can't change `Set`, it's an external library code. But the link you gave explains it perfectly, thanks.

Comment: np - and what I meant is you could use different generic parameter, no need for an external code - I think `Builders<TEncounter>` is what I meant or `Set<TEncounter>`, i.e. the way you're calling it